# White space appears around icon bar

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner at HTML/CSS, so forgive me for any obvious mistakes. I am attempting to create a responsive social media footer using Font Awesome icons and Bootstrap. However, white spaces appear at the sides of the footer. Any idea of how to remove?

[White squares appearing beside the icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WWo1.png)

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
ul {
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
}
.footer-social {
    width: 50%;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.social-icon {
    color: #fff;
 background-color: #000000;
}
.social-icons li {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline;
    height: 100px;
 text-align: center;
}
.social-icons a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.fa-facebook {
    padding:10px 16px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    background-color: #000000;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.fa-facebook:hover {
    background-color: #3d5b99;
 color: #ffffff;
}
.fa-twitter {
    padding:10px 12px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    background-color: #000000;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.fa-twitter:hover {
    background-color: #00aced;
 color: #ffffff;
}
.fa-soundcloud {
    padding:10px 10px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    background-color: #000000;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.fa-soundcloud:hover {
    background-color: #eb8231;
 color: #ffffff;
}
.fa-youtube {
    padding:10px 14px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    background-color: #000000;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.fa-youtube:hover {
    background-color: #e64a41;
 color: #ffffff;
}
.fa-instagram {
    padding:10px 14px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    background-color: #000000;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.fa-instagram:hover {
    background-color: #0073a4;
 color: #ffffff;
}
.fa-spotify {
    padding:10px 14px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    background-color: #000000;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.fa-spotify:hover {
    background-color: #e25714;
 color: #ffffff;
}
div {
 background-color: #000000;

}
```

```html
<div class="footer-social">

<ul class="social-icons">

    <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-soundcloud"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-spotify"></i></a></li>
</ul>


</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.footer-social {
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The footer bar seems to only be at width 50%, try changing it to 100%, that should have it span the whole width of the page.

Comment: Good answer, not only giving the solution by explaining why it works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Helped a lot; not sure why I put 50% in the first place :)

Comment: What a well put together answer

Answer (score 1):

Expand the footer full width:

```
.footer-social {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z8vc9vq4/2/**

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `width: 50%;` from `.footer-social`:

```
.footer-social {
  /* width: 50%; */
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ac8Lyfje/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Set main footer div width as 100%